# Topologically transitive dynamical system mapping space into ball

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a separable Hausdorff topological space and $\phi \in C(X,X)$ be a topologically transitive map.  Further, let $V$ be a fixed non-empty open subset of $X$.  Then does there necessarily exist a countable open cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $X$ and a sequence of natural numbers $\{N_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{N_i}(U_i) \subseteq V?
$$

ie the entire space fits into $V$; eventually?

[$\phi$ is said to be *topologically transitive* iff for every two non-empty open subsets $U,V\subseteq X$ there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$\phi^N(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset$.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Let $\phi$ be the left shift on the set $X = \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ of bi-infinite binary sequences with the prodiscrete topology, and let $V = \{ x \in X : x_0 = 0 \}$ be the set of sequences that have $0$ at the central coordinate.
Then $X$ is Hausdorff (even metrizable and compact), $\phi$ is transitive (even mixing) and $V$ is nonempty and open (even clopen).
The all-$1$ sequence $x = \ldots 1 1 1 \ldots$ satisfies $\phi^n(x) \notin V$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Hence in any open cover $(U_i)_{i \in I}$, some $U_i$ contains $x$ and then $\phi^n(U_i)$ is not a subset of $V$ for any $n$.

Comment: I realise I didn't formalize what I was looking for properly; here is the correct formulation:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344891/reversal-of-open-cover-with-topologically-transitive-dynamical-system