# Reversal of open cover with topologically transitive dynamical system

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a separable metric space, $\phi\in C(X,X)$ be a topologically transitive dynamical system, and $V$ be a non-empty open subset of $X$, and $\nu$ be a locally-positive and atomless Borel probability measure on $X$.

Then, for every $\delta \in (0,1)$, does there exist:

- $\{V_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are open subsets of $V$ satisfying $\nu\left(
  V-\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} V_n
  \right)=0$
- A sequence $\{N_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$,
  *such that the following holds:*
  $$
  \nu\left(X - \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{-N_i}[V_i] \right)<\delta
  .
  $$

*In intuitive words: there exists an open cover of a non-empty open set be reversed into an almost-everywhere cover of the entire space by appropriately reversing the dynamical sytem?*

**Auxiliary Definitions:**

- A Borel measure $\nu$ on $X$ is said to be *locally-positive* iff for every non-empty open subset $U\subseteq X$, $\nu(U)>0$.  *For example, if $X$ has more than two points then the Dirac is not such a measure.*
- $\phi$ is said to be *topologically transitive* iff for every two non-empty open subsets $U,V\subseteq X$ there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
  $$
  \phi^N(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset.
  $$

Comment: If a solution $(V_i, N_i)_i$ exists, then $(V, N_i)_i$ is also a solution, so $\delta_1$ is unimportant. Is this intentional?

Comment: Do you require $V_i$ to be distinct? If not, since the existence of a solution implies $(V, N_i)_i$ is a solution, and if $(V, N_i)_i$ is allowed to be a solution, why not just ignore $V_i$ and work only with $V$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\nu$ is finite? at least locally?

Comment: (Deleted a bunch of comments since they have been clarified and now there are no obvious counterexamples.)

Comment: Thanks you Willie; I'll do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, even if we assume $\nu$ to be invariant under $\phi$.

Let $X = \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of two-way infinite binary sequences with the prodiscrete topology, and let $\phi$ be the left shift on $X$.
Let $\nu = (\mu_1 + \mu_2)/2$ where $\mu_1$ is the uniform Bernoulli measure on $X$ and $\mu_2$ is an atomless $\phi$-invariant probability measure on some proper subshift of $X$.
For simplicity, let's choose $\mu_2$ as the Parry measure on the shift of finite type $Y \subsetneq X$ where $0 0$ is forbidden.
Let $V = \{ x \in X : x_0 = x_1 = 0 \}$ be the set of sequences with an occurrence of the forbidden word $0 0$ at the origin.
These definitions satisfy your requirements: $\phi$ is well-known to be transitive, $\nu$ gives positive measure to each nonempty clopen set (which form a basis of the topology) and has no atoms, and $V$ is a nonempty open set.

Consider an open cover $(V_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $V$ and a sequence $(N_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of integers.
For each $i$ the translate $\phi^{-N_i} V_i$ is disjoint from $Y$, so $\nu(X - \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{-N_i} V_i) \geq \nu(Y) = 1/2$.

**But yes**, if we strengthen the assumptions further.

In my counterexample the ergodic decomposition of $\nu$ features a positive-weight measure $\mu_2$ which is not locally positive.
Let's thus assume that $\nu$ has an ergodic decomposition as an integral $\nu = \int_{E(M_\phi)} x \, d\mu(x)$ over the $\phi$-ergodic probability measures on $X$ and $\mu$-a.e. $x \in E(M_\phi)$ is locally positive.
Then $x(V) > 0$ holds for those measures $x$.
Since they are ergodic, this implies $x(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{-i} V) = 1$, so that $\nu(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{-i} V) = \int x(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{-i} V) \, d\mu(x) = 1$.
Then $V_i = V$ and $N_i = i$ give the sequence you're looking for, for every $\delta > 0$.
Note that even if I didn't use transitivity in this proof, it's implied by the existence of a locally positive ergodic measure.

Depending on your application, the assumptions of $\phi$-invariance and local positivity of the ergodic decomposition may be too strong.
In the context of dynamical systems invariance seems natural, but by itself it's not enough.

Comment: If instead, we strengthen the assumptions on $X$ and $\phi$; namely that it is a separable Banach space and we assume that $\phi$ is linear.  Then the counterexample seems to vanish.  In this case, it's not clear that the added assumptions are still necessary.  Am I right?

Comment: @MrMMS We can do something similar. Let $X = \ell^1$ and $\phi(x)_n = 2 x_{n+1}$. Define $\mu_1$ by first choosing $c$ from a distribution that is locally positive on $[0, \infty)$, and then choosing each $x_n$ independently and uniformly from $[-c/2^n, c/2^n]$. Define $\mu_2$ similarly but with $[0, c/2^n]$. These are invariant, atomless, and $\mu_1$ is locally positive: For an open ball $B_r(y)$, take $N$ with $\sum_{n \geq N} |y| < r/2$. For a $\mu_1$-random $x$, $\sum_{n \geq N} |x| < r/2$ and $\sum_{n < N} |x-y| < r/2$ with positive probability. Take $V = \{ x \in X : x_0 \in (-1,0) \}$.

Comment: By the way, it feels like I'm chasing some moving goalposts here. Do you have a specific dynamical system in mind? Or is the case of linear continuous transitive functions on separable Banach spaces the _exact_ setting that you need?

Comment: It's indeed the exact setting (I was hoping to get something more general) if possible.

Comment: Though now I do wonder if the converse is true; namely, if there is a good lower bound on $\nu\left(X - \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi^{-N_i}[V_i] \right)$.... Though this is a different question entirely (in hopes of removing the added assumptions)

Comment: In both examples, $\nu(X - \bigcup_i \phi^{-i} V)$ can be any number $a \in [0,1]$, since we can choose $\nu = (1-a) \mu_1 + a \mu_2$.

Comment: True.  Alright, in that case I'll find and interpretation of the assumptions in my application.  Thank you very much for all the help.